# How to search Netflix for movies set in countries in Africa?

Tags: netflix

I just joined Netflix hoping to watch movies from many other countries than my own (USA). Right now I'd like to find movies from Africa. I can't see any way of searching for them.

I would prefer something OTHER than documentaries. I would prefer movies not only set in some African country but also about a local theme and directed and played by people from the country. But I will take what I can get.

Answer (score 1):

You will see below that a search using simply the word "africa" on Netflix returns [African Movies](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Collection%3A3761) as well as a lot of other links. Likewise, a search for "international" turns up [International Movies](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=international&suggestionId=Collection%3A78367) as well as other links.

##### Instructions

1. Log in to [Netflix: https://www.netflix.com/login](https://www.netflix.com/login)
2. Type "africa" in the Search box or paste the following URL on the address bar: [`https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa`](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa)
3. You will see a section that reads "Explore titles related to" followed by links similar to:

   - [Africa](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Video%3A70254835)
   - [African Movies](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Collection%3A3761)
   - [The African Queen](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Video%3A60011001)
   - [African Movies & TV](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Collection%3A100369)
   - [African Safari](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Video%3A80138226)
   - [African American Lives](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Video%3A70213099)
   - [African Comedies](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Collection%3A34202)
   - [Romantic African Movies](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Collection%3A59723)
   - [South African Movies](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Collection%3A1159504)
   - [Emotional African Movies](https://www.netflix.com/search?q=africa&suggestionId=Collection%3A59388)

[image]

Comment: Thanks. For some reason, I didn't try just searching for "Africa". I can probrably find some of what I'm looking for here. 
I first started searching for particular country names, like "Algeria" and 90% of the results had nothing to do with the country that I entered. I didn't want to have look up details on every thing listed. It would have taken me forever.

Comment: I marked it useful. But I'll wait to see if there are other answers before I "accept" it. :)

Comment: That's reasonable.

Comment: I checked the details of about 20 movies in "African comedies". Almost every one (except for 2) was from either South Africa or Nigeria. I'll watch a few of those. But I'd still like to find an easier way to discover those from other countries. I tried searches on a few more countries. Almost none of the results were from the country requested. Maybe this is because of the limit of my subscription.

Comment: *"every one (except for 2) was from either South Africa or Nigeria"* Not surprising, the Nigerian film industry is the largest in Africa in terms of annual films, revenue and popularity. **It is also the second-largest film producer in the world.**   You might try https://unogs.com/ to search for films and where they can be streamed.  Also googling for lists of movies turns up things like: [19 Best African movies on Netflix to enjoy in 2023](https://tracystravelsintime.com/2022/06/26/african-movies-on-netflix/).

Comment: Except for 3, all those in "19 Best ..." are from S.A. or Nigeria. But knowing about those 3 is helpful. Will unogs.com be searching all of Netflix's libraries? Is there a way to limit the search to the one that I subscribe to?

Comment: You'll need to do some exploring and searching.  Everything I've shared in the answer and my comments I didn't  know until you asked the question.  If you have a passion for African content that isn't produced in Nigeria or South Africa, but is streamed on Netflix in the US, you'll be answering my questions  soon. Google is your friend.  Find a subreditt or discussion forum with like-minded people that share your interests. I imagine geolocating your Netflix via VPN  to an African country might open up less commercial content